# Stop ssh tuneling session in windows

Tags: windows, ssh

I run `ssh -f user@ssh.example.com -L 3307:mysql1.example.com:3306 -N` to access database in `localhost:3307. because database accept connection only from the webserver.

I have 2 questions:

1. Is that port accessible only from localhost or other people in the same network can access this port
2. How to close the ssh session that is running in the background

Comment: If *mysql1.example.com* and *ssh.example.com* is accessible outside of your network then you certainly are not making a connection to your local machine.  In fact given your example anyone outside of your network could make that connection.

Answer (score 0):

As is, answer would be:

1. No.  Change that to "-L 127.0.0.1:3307:mysql1.example.com:3306"
2. Shutdown any connection to the database and then kill the SSH connection.

Comment: How to kill the ssh connection and why do I need to shutdown the application database?

Comment: Have reworded the above a bit.  You want to kill whatever process is connected to the database.  Doing so will avoid any interrupted write instruction that might corrupt the database.  If the SSH command is running in the foreground, press Ctrl-c.  If it's running in the background, determine it's process ID and use the "kill" command.  Note: depending on your system, you might be able to use "pkill" instead.